# Writing Parser for JSON String

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads

As part of trying to write a JSON Parser, I'm working on parsing a JSON String value.

Given the following definition from Prof. Brent Yorgey's Haskell [course](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/):

```
-- A parser for a value of type a is a function which takes a String
-- represnting the input to be parsed, and succeeds or fails; if it
-- succeeds, it returns the parsed value along with the remainder of
-- the input.
newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }
```

I'm running into trouble since, as I understand, my second parser, `zeroOrMore notEndOfString`, simply consumes every *token* until reaching the end of the String.

`data JValue = S String | ...`

```
parseStringJValue :: Parser JValue
parseStringJValue = S <$> ((char '"') *> (zeroOrMore notEndOfString) <* (char '"'))

notEndOfString :: Parser Char
notEndOfString = Parser f
  where 
    f []     = Nothing
    f (x:xs) = Just (x, xs)
```

Using this applicative approach, please give me a hint towards modifying my above `parseStringJValue` to actually work.

Note - I have a faint idea on how to solve it with Monads, but I'm not sure if if they are required.

Comment: Hint: the String in `notEndOfString` is the result of your parse, not the input to be parsed.

Comment: You probably want `zeroOrMore notEndOfStringOrQuote`. In parsec, for example, I would probably just write `many (noneOf "\"")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notEndOfString` is matching and consuming any characters in the text *including `"`* until the end, so it acts greedily to consume all characters and never hands off to the `char '"'` parser. You need to match any characters inside of the quotes that *aren't a quote*, which means you need the negation of `char`.

If you have `char` then presumably you built it from `satisfy`, which means you can also define `notChar`:

```
notChar c = satisfy (/= c)
```

(Note, by the way, that `notEndOfString` is just `satisfy id`). Otherwise, you can write it similarly to `char`.

Then you can define the parser for strings by building up a few other useful combinators:

```
bracket l r p = l *> p <* r
quotes = bracket (char '"') (char '"')

parseStringJValue = S <$> quotes (zeroOrMore (notChar '"'))
```

Note that this won't handle escapes (`"\""`) within quotes.

---

Edit: To enforce the invariant that is implicit above, it would be nice to define

```
inside l r = bracket (char l) (char r) (zeroOrMore (notChar r))
```

Then `parseStringJValue = S <$> inside '"' '"'`.